# Azure DevOps reports PowerShell task as passed even with non-0 exit code

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, task

In Azure DevOps I have a task to run a PowerShell script. In certain scenarios, the script should exit with a non-0 code, causing the task to be reported as failed. However, Azure DevOps reports the task as passed regardless.

This is a problem because I have a subsequent job that should run if this job fails, but that is not happening because of the false positive.

[image]

The relevant part of the script shows that, in the case of the screenshot, an exit code of `1` was detected, which should result in the script exiting in error.

```
if ($exitCode -ne 0)
{
    Write-Output ("[Error] Failing task since return code was {0} while expected 0." -f $exitCode)
}
exit $exitCode
```

The task is run as part of a `deployment` job, and I do have the option `failOnStandardError` set to `true`.

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: Check Function App Version
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnectionName }}
    scriptType: FilePath
    scriptPath: ${{ parameters.scriptsArtefactPath }}/Test-FunctionAppVersion.ps1
    scriptArguments: -Uri ${{ parameters.healthCheckUri }} -AuthHeaderName Authorization -AuthHeaderValue "$(healthCheckAuthHeaderValue)"
    failOnStandardError: true
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
    pwsh: true
```

How can I make Azure DevOps honour my exit codes?

Comment: I tested a similar case with the regular powershell task.  It worked as expected.  The failOnStandardError flag is really looking for things written to the Error stream I think.  You'd need to do a Write-Error instead to force it.  That isn't what you are asking for though I know.  That being said, I think it is something with the return not getting handled correctly in that task.  I see that they might have [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13432) anyway with that flag for that task anyway.

Comment: If it is a bug, raising it on the github project might be the best way to get some direct relief.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that the Azure PowerShell task has an issue capturing the exit code from a script file, it works fine with the inline scripts. You can [report this problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21) to Microsoft development team. Hope they will provide a fix soon.

However, you can use either of below workarounds to fix it.

1, Use `[Environment]::Exit($exitCode)` instead of `exit`. See below:

```
if ($exitCode -ne 0)
{
    Write-Output ("[Error] Failing task since return code was {0} while expected 0." -f $exitCode)
}
[Environment]::Exit($exitCode)
```

2, Use [logging command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#complete-finish-timeline) `##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed` to manually fail the task if the exitCode is non-0. See below:

```
if ($exitCode -ne 0)
{
    Write-Output ("[Error] Failing task since return code was {0} while expected 0." -f $exitCode)
    Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed"
}
exit $exitCode
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll give those suggestions a try as soon as I get the opportunity.

Comment: Hi @DavidGard Did you get a chance to try above out. How did it go?

Comment: Tested just now and option one seems to do the job. I will add a further comment if I do come across any issues when I'm back in the office next week. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the solution did not directly worked for me, I improved this a little bit and use `Write-Error` instead of `Write-Host`.

```
if ($exitCode -ne 0) {
  Write-Error ("[Error] Failing task since return code was {0} while expected 0." -f $exitCode)
}
```

Combined with the `failOnStderr` you will get what you need.

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: check stuff
  inputs:
    failOnStderr: true
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      do_some_thing
      if ($exitCode -ne 0) {
        Write-Error ("[Error] Failing task since return code was {0} while expected 0." -f $exitCode)
      }
```